# Not able to identify text using monkeyrunner

Tags: python, monkeyrunner

I have a script that finds a text view,get its co-ordinates and click on it. In order to click i have to scroll and find that text view. Script is as below,

```
text = 'abc'
self.device.drag((400,600), (300, 200), 0.01, 120)
tv = self.vc.findViewWithText(text)
if tv:
    (x, y) = tv.getXY()
    print >>sys.stderr, "Clicking TextView %s @ (%d,%d) ..." % (text, x, y)
    tv.touch()
else:
        print "Text is not found" %text
```

It does dragging. Although text 'abc' is present, it prints "Text is not found".

I removed drag() method, and manually did the dragging, it worked fine(identified text and did the clicking).

Can anyone knows whats wrong with my drag() method.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AndroidViewClient.dump()` dumps what is currently displayed on the screen, so if you have to scroll to make the `TextView` visible it won't be in the first (implicit) dump.
Therefore, you have to dump again after scrolling:

```
text = 'abc'
self.device.drag((400,600), (300, 200), 0.01, 120)
MonkeyRunner.sleep(3)
self.vc.dump()
tv = self.vc.findViewWithText(text)
if tv:
    (x, y) = tv.getXY()
    print >>sys.stderr, "Clicking TextView %s @ (%d,%d) ..." % (text, x, y)
    tv.touch()
else:
        print "Text is not found" %text
```

or

```
text = 'abc'
self.device.drag((400,600), (300, 200), 0.01, 120)
MonkeyRunner.sleep(3)
self.vc.dump()
self.vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(text).touch()
```

Also take into accout the point mentioned by [NRP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1838878/nrp) about the sleep.

Answer (score 0):

MonkeyRunner excutes all the commands very fast so some time you have to add sleep before it starts finding a view. so your code will be like.

```
text = 'abc'
self.device.drag((400,600), (300, 200), 0.01, 120)
MonkeyRunner.sleep(1)
tv = self.vc.findViewWithText(text)
if tv:
    (x, y) = tv.getXY()
    print >>sys.stderr, "Clicking TextView %s @ (%d,%d) ..." % (text, x, y)
    tv.touch()
else:
        print "Text is not found" %text
```